# Error: maxFeePerGas cannot be less than maxPriorityFeePerGas

Tags: gnosis-safe

My transaction is failing for no reason, the safe has enough funds and the code seems correct.

```js
const txs = [
        {
          to: contractAddress,
          value: "0",
          data: contract.methods
            .setLimit(token, address, limitPeriod, tokenAmount, startTime)
            .encodeABI(),
        },
      ];
      const params = { safeTxGas: 50000 };
      try {
        const test = await sdk.txs.send({ txs, params });
        
        console.log(test);

      } catch (err: any) {
        console.error(err);
      }
```

Also, my safe address "rin:0x4Ee2256f80Efd8aaCAAa2037F50d523c4b191cb0" has no transactions so I am using nonce 0 in safe nonce and the owner transaction. I set up a gas limit of 25000. I can confirm. But once I confirm with MetaMask, I get an error that makes no sense.

> Error: maxFeePerGas cannot be less than maxPriorityFeePerGas.

Could anyone help? thank you
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We'll allow editing the suggested maxPriorityFee in the upcoming 3.18.0 release.

It's currently set to 2.5 Gwei by default. So if your gas price is lower than that (e.g. 1 Gwei like on your screenshot), it won't work. We're aware of this issue and it [will be fixed](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-react/issues/3393) soon.

In them meanwhile, you can simply increase the gas price to 3 Gwei, or [override the suggested gas price](https://metamask.io/1559/) in your Metamask popup.

[image]